# Generic class for dynamic arrays in c++

Tags: c++, dynamic-memory-allocation

Is it possible to make a generic class that acts as a dynamic array of objects of any type?
I want a class that basically does this:

```
MyObj * obj1 = new MyObj();
MutableArray * arr = new MutableArray();
arr->addObject(obj1);
MyObj * obj2 = arr->objectAtIndex(0);
// obj1 and obj2 now points to the same object
```

This is what the code would look like. I know this doesn't work, but you get the idea. 
What I need is some generic type for an object. The array itself just consists of pointers so the size of the object shouldn't matter, right?

So, is this possible?

**.h-file**

```
class MutableArray
{
    private:
        class * objs;
        int length;
        int capacity;

    public:
        MutableArray();
        void add(class * obj);
        class objectAtIndex(int index);
};
```

**cpp-file**

```
MutableArray::MutableArray()
{
    length = 0;
    capacity = 0;
}

void MutableArray::add(class * obj)
{
    if(length >= capacity)
    {
        this->enlarge();
    }
    objs[length] = obj;
    length++;
}

void MutableArray::enlarge()
{
    int newCapacity = (capacity * 2)+1;
    class * newObjs = new class[newCapacity]

    if(capacity != 0)
    {
        delete [] objs;
    }

    objs = newObjs;
    capacity = newCapacity;
}

class MutableArray::objectAtIndex(int index)
{
    return objs[index];
}
```

Comment: Have you considered `std::vector`?

Comment: [Welcome to C++](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/templates/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has already been invented and is called `std::vector<>`.

Comment: Oh, nice :D I've been reading about dynamic arrays for hours and no example brought this up... strange! Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to make a generic class that acts as a dynamic array of objects of any type?

For the dynamic array use `std::vector`, for objects of any type use `boost::any`.

```
std::vector< boost::any > anything;
```

Comment: From the question, it looks like he's not even asking for the array to contain objects of different types at runtime, so a std::vector of his type should do.

Comment: @Rob K: He asks about objects of any type, and tries to implement it as `class * obj` (pointer to any class, maybe?). So I guess he does.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use STL `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It actually exists and is called `std::vector`.